# Running java in android

Tags: emulators, java

Is there any way to run .jar files in android without rooting phone?
I used jbed and some other apps but they instantly stopped unexpectedly after clicking.

Comment: You could try [J2ME Loader](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/ua.naiksoftware.j2meloader) (link goes to my F-Droid compatible repo). Didn't try it myself, so no guarantees – and feedback welcome :)

Comment: It says error detected on all jar apps

Comment: What type of `.jar` do you want to run? A Java command-line program? A Java Swing/AWT program or a JavaFX application?